# Rails 6 assets precompile failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

assets precompile fail. i have tried

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and its still not working.

this is what i am getting

```
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 80f7792c62f7678693d5b0a156516502662ee0ef
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 80f7792c62f7678693d5b0a156516502662ee0ef
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to online-edukation.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/online-edukation.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/online-edukation.git'
```

what could be the cause please?

Comment: Couple of things to check - Make sure you are on the `master` branch and make sure that you have done `git pull` first

Comment: okay thank you. it seems thats not the case.   ```ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stylesheets/application.scss' in '/tmp/build_35bb4e62/app/javascript/packs'
``` this is the error

Comment: try `git pushheroku master -f` to force-push

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here you should look into. Errors aren't always clearly displayed in heroku cli. It can be a few things, like credentials or you're not pushing properly to heroku. Before you do this check your heroku error log (in your heroku dashboard.) or `run heroku logs`, you'll be surprised what you find there.

First make sure you precompile the assets on your local machine before you push to heroku. So maybe something like this.

Create a new branch and make sure you got your current work committed safely in your master or whichever branch.

```
git checkout -b test_heroku
```

Now you can do what you want with this branch. Let test a few things.
Go and remove all the `Rails.application.credentials` objects in you app in case you used fb apps, or stripe or twillio or any other third party vendor. Please replace these objects with test keys (never real keys). For example stripe has test mode key and so does FB, just replace them and destroy the `config/credentials.yml.enc and config/master.key` for now in this test branch.

```
# Make sure you remove `Rails.application.credentials` objects and replace them with test credentials in your files such as stripe.rb or twillio.rb etc..

rake assets:precompile
git add . 

git commit -m "testing"
git push --set-upstream origin test_heroku
```

Note you can always delete this test_heroku git branch later. I am just suggesting this, so that you can track the progress of the events / changes you are making in order to make it work. Then after this you can create a new branch or modify the master branch.

```
git push heroku test_heroku:main
```

If this doesn't work you can try

```
git push heroku test_heroku:main --force
```

You can use --force, it's fine. Unless you want new Heroku instances to deploy test branches to new servers. Different topic.

Anyways just letting you know, if you push to heroku now, you should be fine and it should work if this was a precompile issue due to a miss-configuration or mishap on the secret credentials.

If this works delete your git heroku_test branch fix the errors and do it again.

If this is a precompile issue with credentials (because I can't see the error logs in your question.) I suggest you have a look at this issue here. It seems like this was an issue to many people getting `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` from Rails.application.credentials objects
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947